# Merging smaller chunks of data into one big section of memory

Tags: c++, pointers, copymemory

I have code like this:

```
ByteArray ret;
ret.resize( MAX( body_left, tmp_read.size() ) );
while ( body_left > 0 ) {
    ByteArray::Write r = tmp_read.write();
    int rec = 0;
    err = connection->get_partial_data( r.ptr(), MIN( body_left, tmp_read.size() ), rec );
    if ( rec > 0 ) {
        ByteArray::Write w = ret.write();
        copymem( w.ptr(), r.ptr(), rec );
        body_left -= rec;
    }
}
```

I find it challenging to understand this code. A few questions:

Is `ret.resize(MAX(body_left,tmp_read.size()));` allocating the `ByteArray` of highest `body_left` or `tmp_read.size()`?

In `ByteArray::Write r = tmp_read.write();` does `r` become a pointer to location in space that is going to be used to write data?

In `ByteArray::Write w = ret.write();`, does `w` become a pointer like `r` in the previous question?

Also, in this line:

```
copymem(w.ptr(),r.ptr(),rec);
```

As I understand this line, all of the data that is gathered under pointer `r` is copied to location  under the pointer `w`. The problem is that they are different size, how to move pointer `w.ptr()` to keep data intact and in correct order? Or is `w.ptr()` is a pointer to function and this should not be a problem.

---

Extra context:

Method `get_partial_data` returns chunks of data - lets say 20, 20, and 10 bytes each.
Variable `ret` is supposed to be 50 bytes long and have those chunks merged into one `ByteArray`.

Unfortunately I cannot find the definition of `ByteArray` in this project, so I guess it's part of another library (libGL maybe?).

I know this question is not very precise and I am making a leap of faith, but if anyone can assist me I would be grateful.

Original class and project this code was taken from:

https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/blob/master/core/io/http_client.cpp

Lines 503-516.

It's in different shape, as I already have applied dirty hack (that does not work to well).

Comment: If it makes you feel better, I'm a reasonably proficient C++ developer (even if I say so myself), but this code doesn't make much sense to me, either. It uses some kind of a class library I've never seen before.

Comment: Where did you find the code?

Comment: Hah! :) Thanks guys, I am updating question with link to project and some extra data.

Comment: [ByteArray is just a typedef.](https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/search?l=cpp&q=bytearray&utf8=%E2%9C%93) And [write()](https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/blob/9ff6d55822647c87eef392147ea15641d0922d47/core/dvector.h) doesn't return a pointer, so they're not pointers I think.

Comment: As for copymem, it's a [macro](https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/blob/9ff6d55822647c87eef392147ea15641d0922d47/core/os/copymem.h). I'm not that well versed in C++ so somebody else can answer your question.

Comment: Thank you very much so far, at least I have some basics explained. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is ret.resize(MAX(body_left,tmp_read.size())); allocating the
>   ByteArray of highest body_left or tmp_read.size()?

`MAX` most likely is a macro that returns the greater of the two arguments. The line `ret.resize(MAX(body_left,tmp_read.size()));` ensures that `ret` is large enough for whatever writing operations that may occur.

> In ByteArray::Write r = tmp_read.write(); does r become a pointer to
>   location in space that is going to be used to write data?
>
> In ByteArray::Write w = ret.write();, does w become a pointer like r
>   in the previous question?

[Write](https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/blob/9ff6d55822647c87eef392147ea15641d0922d47/core/dvector.h#L187) is a class defined on line 187. [write()](https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/blob/9ff6d55822647c87eef392147ea15641d0922d47/core/dvector.h#L209) is a function defined on line 209 that returns a `Write` object, not a pointer. Therefore `r` and `w` are never pointers.

```
class Write {
  // ...
};

Write write() {
  Write w;
  // ...
  return w; 
}
```

> Also, in this line:
>
> ```
> copymem(w.ptr(),r.ptr(),rec);
> ```
>
> As I understand this line, all of the data that is gathered under
>   pointer r is copied to location under the pointer w. The problem is
>   that they are different size, how to move pointer w.ptr() to keep data
>   intact and in correct order? Or is w.ptr() is a pointer to function
>   and this should not be a problem.

[copymem](https://github.com/okamstudio/godot/blob/9ff6d55822647c87eef392147ea15641d0922d47/core/os/copymem.h#L36) is a macro defined on line 36.

```
#define copymem(m_to,m_from,m_count) \
do { \
  unsigned char * _from=(unsigned char*)m_from; \
  unsigned char * _to=(unsigned char*)m_to; \
  int _count=m_count; \
  for (int _i=0;_i<_count;_i++) \
    _to[_i]=_from[_i]; \
} while (0);
```

All this code appears to do is copy the contents of `m_from` to `m_to`. `get_partial_data` feeds the amount to read into `rec`, which is passed to `copymem` as `m_count`.

Comment: There is still one thing that is unclear for me, line: copymem(w.ptr(),r.ptr(),rec), assuming that w.ptr() is a pointer to location in memory that consists our data. Would be that sufficient to do set of operations like that: copymem(w.ptr(),r.ptr(),rec), copymem(w.ptr() + 20,r.ptr(),rec), copymem(w.ptr() + 40,r.ptr(),rec) (assuming we received 20, 20 and 10 bytes like in original question I am asking)

Comment: Well maybe I will add helper question. Line like that: unsigned char * _from=(unsigned char*)m_from, is it creating new variable that will be a pointer to unsigned char and pointer value (location) is calculated as a cast to pointer unsigned char from anything that m_from can be?

Comment: you are my life saviour. Thank to yours explanations I figured out everything. Maybe my solution is not the best but works. I am only concerned with memory leaks right now. Not sure how to detect those. I will post my code, if anyone could take a look and confirm that my code is all right in terms you have seen much worse and it does the job without violating every possible good practice rule in C++ world out there.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap everything I (we) have learnt so far:

Original code was as follows:

```
    ByteArray::Write r = tmp_read.write();
    int rec=0;
    err = connection->get_partial_data(r.ptr(),MIN(body_left,tmp_read.size()),rec);
    if (rec>0) {
        ByteArray ret;
        ret.resize(rec);
        ByteArray::Write w = ret.write();
        copymem(w.ptr(),r.ptr(),rec);
        body_left-=rec;
        if (body_left==0) {
            status=STATUS_CONNECTED;
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Where copymem is a macro that looks as follows:

```
    #define copymem(m_to,m_from,m_count) \
    do { \
      unsigned char * _from=(unsigned char*)m_from; \
      unsigned char * _to=(unsigned char*)m_to; \
      int _count=m_count; \
      for (int _i=0;_i<_count;_i++) \
        _to[_i]=_from[_i]; \
    } while (0);
```

Using everything that remyable explained to me I dropped macro usage, because as I understand w.ptr() returns section of the memory and macro always starts coping from the first byte of that section. Macro do not support offset-ing nor passing pointers.

End result looks as follows:

```
    ByteArray ret;
    ret.resize(MAX(body_left,tmp_read.size()));
    ByteArray::Write w = ret.write();
    unsigned char * _to = (unsigned char*) w.ptr();
    int _offset = 0;
    while (body_left > 0) {
        ByteArray::Write r = tmp_read.write();
        int rec=0;
        err = connection->get_partial_data(r.ptr(),MIN(body_left,tmp_read.size()),rec);
        if (rec>0) {
            unsigned char * _from=(unsigned char*)r.ptr();
            for (int _i=0;_i<rec;_i++)
                _to[_offset+_i]=_from[_i];
            _offset += rec;
            body_left-=rec;
        }
    }
    if (body_left==0) {
        status=STATUS_CONNECTED;
    }
    return ret;
```

Anyone can confirm this is viable solution or even suggest improvement?

Update. I found that I can actually move w.ptr() by offset for a macro, alternative code looks as follow:

```
    ByteArray ret;
    ret.resize(MAX(body_left,tmp_read.size()));
    ByteArray::Write w = ret.write();
    int _offset = 0;
    while (body_left > 0) {
        ByteArray::Write r = tmp_read.write();
        int rec=0;
        err = connection->get_partial_data(r.ptr(),MIN(body_left,tmp_read.size()),rec);
        if (rec>0) {
            copymem(w.ptr()+_offset,r.ptr(),rec);
            body_left-=rec;
            _offset += rec;
        }
    }
    if (body_left==0) {
        status=STATUS_CONNECTED;
    }
    return ret;
```

Comments/opinions?